# i is not incremented within JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

```
for (i = 1; i < this.people.length; i++) {
        peoplePicks[i] = this.people[i].chooseAction(peopleChoices[i]);
    }
```

I have this for loop within my JavaScript program. It runs for ever, even though the length of the array that I am passing to it is 2. when I print the value of i after the statement of the for loop, I get 0. So it seems like i is being decremented by executing the for loop's statement. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does that `chooseAction()` function look like? In the code you posted, there's no declaration for `i`. If that's the same case in that `chooseAction()` function, then that's your problem.

Comment: What happens if you change the `for` loop so that it's `for (var i = 1; ...`?

Comment: In the chooseAction() function, I use another for loop of the form 
for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {}. Is that whats causing the problem?

Comment: @H.F. Yes, it is.

Comment: Adding var i = 1 does fix it. Thanks! Why is this?

Comment: If you don't *declare* `i` with `var` or `let`, it will be assumed to be a **global** variable. Thus every function with a `for (i = 1; ...` loop will use the very same `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var` before your `i` variable in the initialising of your `for loop`.

Like this `for (var i = 1; i < this.people.length; i++) {`

Comment: Adding var i = 1 does fix it. Thanks! Why is this?

Comment: @H.F. You need to set I as a variable as you would with any other variable you create. A for loop is something I have struggled with as well. Remember that the for loop sets a variable first and then changes and uses it however you wish after then discards it after the loop of finished looping. No problem. You’re welcome.